# React default className ... Before ternary operator kicks in

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

```
import './App.css'
import {Button} from "antd"

<Button
    shape="round"
    className={
    istrue === "itstrue" ? "trueclass" : "trueclass active"
    }
    >
        TEXT
</Button>
```

Is it possible to set a default className ... just to start because `const [istrue, setIsTrue] = useState(["itstrue"]);` isn't working. It starts with itstrue state but ... the button always starts out with the non active state. I need it to start with the `active` state.

Can someone please help me? Thank you

Comment: *"I need it to start with the active state."* Why do you initialize `istrue` so that it selects the non-active state then? Or am I misunderstanding? I was about to say that given `useState(["itstrue"])`, `istrue === "itstrue"` will be `false` on first render because you are comparing an array against a string... but that in turn would mean that `"trueclass active"` (which I assume is the active state) is selected, so it would do what you wanted. It's not clear what exactly you want to happen.

Comment: `useState("itstrue")`.  Also, if you conditionally want to add classes, `clsx` would be a good choice.    https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx

Comment: @FelixKling ... It's working fine and starts in `trueclass` right now ... but i want it to start in the active class name `trueclass active` ... not `trueclass` .... when I reverse the condition for != `istrue !== "itstrue" ? "trueclass active" : "trueclass"` ... it still starts with `trueclass` even when I tried to make it start with `truestart active`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the conditional class names in react as:

```
className={"trueclass " + (!itstrue ? 'active' : '')}
```

By this the `trueclass` will be applied independent of the condition and the class `active` will only be applied when `itstrue` is false.

Comment: I want it to start in the active class though ... that's the whole predicament. When I reverse the condition for != ... it still starts will non active class. idk why.

Comment: Use `const [itstrue, setIsTrue] = useState(["false"]);`, so the `itstrue ` will be set to false and hence the condition will work since we gave `! itstrue ` as false

Comment: isTrue has 3 values ... i just gave that var name for reference. there are 3 values, where each value of istrue has it's own class. so 6 classes in total are there. `istrue === "itstrue" ? "trueclass" : "trueclass active"` is correct ... but I just want it to start in trueclass active ... but idt it's possible now that I've done research. I'll just have to rewrite it in an inverse way.